# Parameter ID changes with custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the `form_for` is as so:

```
<%= form_for @reservation, remote: true do |f| %>
```

I get the following params:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "reservation"=>{"party_size"=>"1",
>   "persons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"Big Name",
>   "last_name"=>"test", "meal_id"=>"1", "id"=>"24"},
>   "1"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "meal_id"=>"1"}},
>   "address"=>"test", "city"=>"Test", "state"=>"te", "zip"=>"te"},
>   "commit"=>"submit", "id"=>"24"}

But when I put a custom controller onto the `form_for`, as so

```
<%= form_for @reservation, url: {controller: 'static_pages'}, remote: true do |f| %>
```

I get the following params:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "reservation"=>{"party_size"=>"1",
>   "persons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"Big Name",
>   "last_name"=>"test", "meal_id"=>"1", "id"=>"24"},
>   "1"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "meal_id"=>"1"}},
>   "address"=>"test", "city"=>"Test", "state"=>"te", "zip"=>"te"},
>   "commit"=>"submit", "id"=>"index"}

How do I ensure that the `params[:id]` remains the same? All I need is the standard `form_for` with a different controller called (the same for is used for both `new`\ `create` and `edit`\ `update`).

Answer (score 0):

'form_for' with an active record object tries to identify the URL from the object. If it has an ID, it uses the update route, otherwise it uses the create route. Initially it identifies it as something like

> /reservation/1

But when you explicitly pass something as the URL it will override it. Now our URL looks like

> /reservation/index

I recommend looking into the 'form_for' documentation, but what could really solve your problem would be to explicitly pass the whole URL, instead of just the controller. That way you could get the ID in the right place

Answer (score 0):

In the form you can place the following line of code which will pass the :id to the controller in the POST request.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, params[:id]) %>
```

You might have to add a method to convert it to an integer within the controller.

```
params[:id].to_i
```

Depending on how you have your db setup.